# Get multiple selections from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have a listbox in my wpf-app:

```
<ListBox x:Name="detailComponentListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,65,0,10" Width="171" ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentList}" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedComponent}"/>
```

The selectedValue property is binded to:

```
public String selectedComponent
  {
      set
      {
        MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        foreach (String test in mw.detailComponentListBox.SelectedItems)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
      }
  }
```

So that when the user clicks an item (adds it to the selection) all selected items should be printed to the console. But instead all items are printed except(!) the one that is selected. The missing item is only printed the next click in the listbox (e.g. unselect that item or select another one, which then too will not be printed... and so on). How can this case be handled?

**Background**: I have an app that displays entities from a database. When an entity is selected one property is visualized through that listbox (the entity "contains" the items from the listbox). The user can then add/remove items from the listbox through selection via mouseclick. These changes should be immediatly pushed to the database. For that i need to capture the "select/unselect event" of the listbox and read the selected items.

Comment: Instead of binding SelectedValue (which should actually be SelectedItem), you might perhaps better handle the SelectionChanged event.

Comment: I tried selectedItem also. There was no change in behaviour. I will look into the SelectedChange event. Thank you.

Comment: @Clemens selectionChanged would work, but this does not conform with the mvvm pattern. I did'nt found a working solution for using mvvm with selectionchanged. Can you help?

Comment: Using `Application.Current.MainWindow` in a "view model" property setter is even more far from MVVM. You may search the web for an implementation of an attached property that wraps the SelectedItems property to make it bindable.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for your help - even if it does not answer my question.

Comment: My comments were not supposed to provide an answer. Search the web for "bind selecteditems".